# MFC C++ Edit Windows Controls in Callback Function

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, mfc, callback

I got stuck at this part of my project.
I have a Download dialog which when you double click listcontrol.
I create it dynamicly and its use a static pointer to a Class which handles Download/Upload processes at FTP.

Well everything is fine here.

Every download process use a thread in this class.and i post a static callback function(thread functions does not accept non-static functions)

But I want to edit my Windows's controls in this callback function what should i do ?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a parameter to your thread being the `m_hWnd` of your dialog. Then on completion of the work done by the thread use [`PostMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to send a message to the dialog class to handle updating of it's controls.

Comment: Yes passing the dialog as parameter would be ok.I did not do this because I didnt want to mess code.I guess there is not another option.So I choose this as Anwswer.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See this example of using the PostMessage technique:

http://vcfaq.mvps.org/mfc/12.htm

Comment: I passed "this" pointer to my function.I can edit some public string variables etc.But i can't use my pointer to dialog to change controls like MyDlg->blaleditbox1.SetWindowTextA("blabla");
but some of public variables works great.
Actually I don't want to use the PostMessage func.Because its make my code unreadable

Comment: @h3x0r For thread safety reasons MFC does not permit you to access a window (like an edit control) that was created in another thread. So the PostMessage technique is necessary.